# White line of toolbar icon in Sencha Touch2 Android

Tags: android, extjs, sencha-touch-2

Toolbar iconmask button in Sencha Touch2 problem.
At iPhone, there is no problem.

But android, there is white line in toolbar button icon.

It is not all icons at the applicatoin.

Some button has the line, another has.
And whereas same iconCls, at some view has the line, at the another view does not.

My test device is 201HW, Android 4.0.4.

Comment: I'd check to see if maybe some of your custom CSS interferes with the button icon layout.

Comment: I tried removing all my custom CSS files, but the bugs still appears.

Answer (score 0):

First of all check to see if the size of the mask `-webkit-mask-size` is the same with the container size(*width height*).

If this problem is only on Android: you should set `z-index` property for the parent container of the mask.

Comment: Thank you.

This is only Android problem.

The mask HTML is this: 
`<div class="x-button x-iconalign-center x-button-action" id="ext-button-11">
 <span style="display: none;" class="x-badge"></span>
 <span class="x-button-icon settings x-icon-mask" style="" id="ext-element-157"></span>
 <span style="display: none;" class="x-button-label"></span>
</div>'

so, you mean set z-index to "<span class="x-button-icon settings x-icon-mask" style="" id="ext-element-157"></span>" ?

But can not set z-index this tag.

Comment: the .x-button class has z-index: 1 so the problem is not there

Comment: Check the -webkit-mask-size property and the container(.settings) dimensions or if you have an url I can take a look.

Comment: -webkit-mask-size is 19.5px;(1.3em).

Please tell me what is the container(.settings) dimensions?
.setting class is written -webkit-mask-image. Do you mean the dimensions of the image?

Comment: .settings{ -webkit-mask-size: 1.3em 1.3em; width: 1.3em; height: 1.3em; ... }

Comment: .settings{ -webkit-mask-image: url(...)} is all. I use Sencha Touch 2.0

Comment: .x-icon-mask is, .x-icon-mask{  width: 1.3em;height: 1.3em;  -webkit-mask-size: 1.3em;}

Comment: do you have this at an url?

Comment: I have a samsung tablet with the same android version (Android 4.0.4) and i can't see the white line. I suppose it should be on the settings button from the panel with search icon. Maybe the problem is with the ~10px height line that appears after the tab bar.